# doctrine entity manager duplicate insert on update

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.1

I have build a cli application with Symfony full stack that processes XLSX files. However, updating information in a database record at 2 different points leads to the record being duplicated instead of updated.

A most simple breakdown of the application is:

**Command**

```
class AppProcessFilesCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $em = $this-setContainer>getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $file = $em->getRepository( 'AppBundle:FileToSync' )->findBy(
                ['processed' => null],
                ['modified' => 'ASC']
            );
            if (sizeof($file) > 0) {
                $file = $file[0];

                foreach (ProcessorFactory::getAvailableProcessors() as $processor) {
                    $start = microtime( true );                        
                    if (ProcessorFactory::getInstance( $processor )
                                        ->setOutput( $output )
                                        ->setContainer( $this->getContainer() )
                                        ->setDoctrine( $this->getContainer()->get( 'doctrine' ) )
                                        ->process( $file )
                    ) {
                        $processorFound = true;
                        $file->setTimeTaken( microtime( true ) - $start );
                        $file->setProcessed( new \DateTime() );
                        $em->persist($file);
                        $em->flush();
                    }
                }
```

**Processing loop**

```
class Processor
{
    public function process($fileToSync)
    {
        $foundFiles = $this->convertToCsv($file);
        $noRows = $this->processCsvSheets($foundFiles, $fileToSync);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $fileToSync->setDetectedTypeId($this->getMyFileTypeId());
        $fileToSync->setRowCount($noRows);
        $em->persist($fileToSync);
        $em->flush();
```

**Entity class**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;


class FileToSync
{
    private $id;

    private $absolute_path;

    private $modified;

    private $processed;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $detected_type_id;

    private $time_taken;

    private $row_count;

        /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\DetectedType
     */
    private $DetectedType;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set absolutePath
     *
     * @param string $absolutePath
     *
     * @return FileToSync
     */
    public function setAbsolutePath($absolutePath)
    {
        $this->absolute_path = $absolutePath;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get absolutePath
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return $this->absolute_path;
    }

    /**
     * Set modified
     *
     * @param \DateTime $modified
     *
     * @return FileToSync
     */
    public function setModified($modified)
    {
        $this->modified = $modified;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get modified
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getModified()
    {
        return $this->modified;
    }

    /**
     * Set detectedTypeId
     *
     * @param \integer $detectedTypeId
     *
     * @return FileToSync
     */
    public function setDetectedTypeId($detectedTypeId)
    {
        $this->detected_type_id = $detectedTypeId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get detectedTypeId
     *
     * @return \integer
     */
    public function getDetectedTypeId()
    {
        return $this->detected_type_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set processed
     *
     * @param \datetime $processed
     *
     * @return FileToSync
     */
    public function setProcessed(\datetime $processed)
    {
        $this->processed = $processed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get processed
     *
     * @return \datetime
     */
    public function getProcessed()
    {
        return $this->processed;
    }

    /**
     * Set detectedType
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\DetectedType $detectedType
     *
     * @return FileToSync
     */
    public function setDetectedType(\AppBundle\Entity\DetectedType $detectedType = null)
    {
        $this->DetectedType = $detectedType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get detectedType
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\DetectedType
     */
    public function getDetectedType()
    {
        return $this->DetectedType;
    }

    /**
     * Set timeTaken
     *
     * @param string $timeTaken
     *
     * @return FileToSync
     */
    public function setTimeTaken($timeTaken)
    {
        $this->time_taken = $timeTaken;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get timeTaken
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTimeTaken()
    {
        return $this->time_taken;
    }

    /**
     * Set rowCount
     *
     * @param integer $rowCount
     *
     * @return FileToSync
     */
    public function setRowCount($rowCount)
    {
        $this->row_count = $rowCount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rowCount
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getRowCount()
    {
        return $this->row_count;
    }
}
```

**Entity Mapping (yml)**

```
AppBundle\Entity\DetectedType:
    type: entity
    table: detected_type
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 501

AppBundle\Entity\FileToSync:
    type: entity
    table: file_to_sync
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    manyToOne:
        DetectedType:
            targetEntity: DetectedType
            joinColumn:
                name: detected_type_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    fields:
        absolute_path:
            type: string
            length: 255
        modified:
            type: datetime
        detected_type_id:
            type: integer
            nullable: true
        processed:
            type: datetime
            nullable: true
        time_taken:
            type: decimal
            precision: 11
            scale: 6
            nullable: true
        row_count:
            type: integer
            nullable: true


AppBundle\Entity\Transaction:
    type: entity
    table: transaction
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    uniqueConstraints:
        txnId:
          columns: [ txn_id ]
    manyToOne:
        FileToSync:
            targetEntity: FileToSync
            joinColumn:
                name: file_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    fields:
        txnDate:
            type: datetime
        file_id:
            type: integer
```

In the processing loop, $fileToSync is not updated, but rather a new record inserted. This is then updated in the command.

I am working under the assumption that $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager(); works as a Singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by default symfony2 services work like singleton, you can read this:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html

> Understanding Scopes¶
>
> The scope of a service controls how long an instance of a service is
>   used by the container. The Dependency Injection component provides two
>   generic scopes:
>
> container (the default one): The same instance is used each time you
>   request it from this container. prototype: A new instance is created
>   each time you request the service

Firsly, you can not use persist method if your 'file' entity was loaded from entityManager.
Second dump 'file' entity before flush and check what you try to save.
Also you can check entity status at UnitOfWork here sample:

```
$unitOfWork = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();

foreach ($unitOfWork->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
   #for insert
}

foreach ($unitOfWork->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
    # for update
}
```

> The semantics of the persist operation, applied on an entity X, are as
>   follows:
>
> If X is a new entity, it becomes managed. The entity X will be entered
>   into the database as a result of the flush operation. If X is a
>   preexisting managed entity, it is ignored by the persist operation.
>   However, the persist operation is cascaded to entities referenced by
>   X, if the relationships from X to these other entities are mapped with
>   cascade=PERSIST or cascade=ALL (see “Transitive Persistence”). If X is
>   a removed entity, it becomes managed. If X is a detached entity, an
>   exception will be thrown on flush.

I thought you are mapping entity in class, but you are not and i can't understand which relation you are using with 'DetectedType'.
This problem might happen if you call 'clear' method somewhere or if your have problem with relation owning side, please read this:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html

Comment: Have added entity class

Comment: Have added yml mapping information. I guess the problem could be that FileToSync is not the "owner" of the relation with Transaction, will try to remove it and see if that fixes the problem. I'm not using the clear() method anywhere